# Divide to Size of array in Kotlin, but I get zero, even size of array equals to 1 or more

Tags: arrays, kotlin

```
    fun plusMinus(arr: Array<Int>): Unit {
    var counterPositive = 0
    var counterNegative = 0
    var counterZero = 0
    for(i in 0 until arr.size) {
        if(arr[i] > 0) {
            counterPositive++
        } else if(arr[i] < 0) {
            counterNegative++
        } else {
            counterZero++
        }
    }

    println(counterPositive)
    println(arr.size)
    val a = counterPositive/arr.size
    println(a)
}
```

I try to solve simple algorithm question, but I face this interesting thing.
So, i try to find positive, negative numbers, and zeros in array. And each one divide to size of array. And print it
But i get 0 as result. But when i debug code i see that counterPositive is for example 4 and arr.size for example 5 but i get 0. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get zero since `counterPositive`, `counterNegative` and `counterZero` are initialized with `0` so the type `Int` is inferred.

Since the array size is an `Int`, the division between two `Int` results in an `Int`.

To fix it, you'd need to use a `Float` or a `Double`.

```kotlin
val a = counterPositive.toFloat() / arr.size
```